# Access O365 Exchange Online with an Azure Managed Identity or Service Principal

Tags: azure, powershell, exchange-server, azure-managed-identity

I have a program in Powershell which runs in an Azure Function app which also has a managed identity called "AuditO365". It uses the managed identity to connect to Azure Key Vault to retrieve user credentials. It uses these credentials to connect to O365 Exchange Online to get the required data. This works fine:

```
    $uSecret = $ENV:APPSETTING_SecretUsername
    $pSecret = $ENV:APPSETTING_SecretPassword 
    $sasSecret = $ENV:APPSETTING_SecretSAS

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pSecret -AsPlainText -Force

    $UserCredential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $uSecret, $securePassword

    $session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $session
```

The credential is a basic user account created in Azure Active Directory and the user is visible to the data source (O365 Exchange Online). In O365 under Exchange Admin Centre, I can see the username and I am able to assign the username to the correct custom role group ("View Audit Readers") with the required permission ("View-Only Audit Logs").

[image]

However I would now like to try using a managed identity instead so that the solution is more robust. Since the Function already has a managed identity ("AuditO365"), I'd like to replace the current user account with this identity in the custom role group in Exchange Online above, but it appears that O365 can't see the managed identity! All the Azure resources and O365 are running under the same account/subscription.

I have also tried creating a service principal (with API permissions for O365) in Azure but this also cannot be seen by O365:

[image]

**1.** How can I make the Azure Function's managed identity visible to O365 / Exchange Online?

**2.** Can I use this managed identity to authenticate the app against Exchange Online, connect and retrieve the data as it currently does with a normal user account?

Comment: Is it useful for you? If it is helpful for you, could you please accept it as an answer?

Comment: I will give this a go and get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to connect Exchange Online in Azure function with Azure MSI,  please refer to the [blog](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2997/connecting-to-exchange-online-powershell-via-client-secret-flow)

The detailed steps are as below.

1. Create Azure function
2. [Enable Azure MSI for Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity)
3. Configure some settings for the MSI

   a.  Assign Exchange Online API permissions `Exchange.ManageAsApp` to the MSI. After doing that, the application has permission to manage Exchange Online

   ```
   Connect-AzureAD

   #assign permmions
   $sp =Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter  "displayName eq 'Office 365 Exchange Online'"

   $permision=$sp.AppRoles.Where({$_.Value -eq 'Exchange.ManageAsApp'})

   New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId <the Objectid of MSI> -Id $permision[0].Id -PrincipalId <the Objectid of MSI> -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId
   ```

   b. Assign Azure AD roles.
   The application needs to have the appropriate AD roles assigned. Because the apps are provisioned in Azure AD, you can use any of the built-in roles. The following roles are supported:

   - Global administrator
   - Compliance administrator
   - Security reader
   - Security administrator
   - Helpdesk administrator
   - Exchange administrator
   - Global Reader

   Regarding how to assign a role, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal?context=azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/context/ugr-context). For example

   ```
   Connect-AzureAD
   #assign role
   $role=Get-AzureADDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Global Reader'"

   Add-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $role.ObjectId -RefObjectId a5d5a5e1-0f26-474d-a105-3553004c973b
   ```
4. Function

```
#get token with MSI
$resourceURI = "https://outlook.office365.com/"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=2019-08-01"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"X-IDENTITY-HEADER"="$env:IDENTITY_HEADER"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
$Authorization = "Bearer {0}" -f $accessToken 
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Authorization -Force

$Ctoken = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "OAuthUser@<your tenant GUID>",$Password
 
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-LiveId?BasicAuthToOAuthConversion=true -Credential $Ctoken -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection -Verbose
Import-PSSession $Session | Format-List

Get-Mailbox 

Remove-PSSession $Session
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this, but didn't work on the 3rd line of the section where we get the token for the MSI. 

See [image](https://imgur.com/a/wyAcyKh)

Comment: Also 

`$role=Get-AzureADDirectoryRole -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Global Reader'"` didn't work. 

Amended it to the following and it seemed to work: 

`$role = (Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | where-object {$_.DisplayName -eq "Global Reader"}).Objectid`

Comment: @MAK Could you please tell me who you where you run the script?

Comment: Cloud shell window from within the Azure portal.

Comment: @MAK in Azure cloud shell, we cannot run the above script.Because we have no way to use Function MSI to get access token.

Comment: @MAK please run the script in Azure function.

Comment: Tried it again. Here are the error messages complaining about [missing modules](https://imgur.com/a/Wn4fla1)

Comment: Which are the values for $env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT and $env:IDENTITY_HEADER?

Comment: @Drumor When you enable Azure MSI in Azure function, these will be stored as environment variable in Azure function.

Comment: Connection to the security and compliance centre doesn't work. Are all cmdlets loaded this way?